# How to deploy to Maven repo from Bazel

Tags: maven, bazel

I need to be able to deploy artifacts to Maven repository that were originally built by Bazel. (e.g. `java_library` Bazel targets) How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `graknlabs/bazel-distribution` rules:

1. `assemble_maven` [link](https://github.com/graknlabs/bazel-distribution#assemble_maven) - for creating the artifact's jar, pom file, etc...
2. `deploy_maven` [link](https://github.com/graknlabs/bazel-distribution#deploy_maven) - for deployment of artifact to specified maven repository

For more information see **Step 3: Setup Bazel configuration** in this [medium article](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/how-to-publish-artifacts-from-bazel-to-maven-central-71da0cf990f5)

Comment: how do i use this ?

Comment: Did you check the documentation in the link? did you read the medium article?

Comment: yes thanks, missed the medium article at first. i was able to create the jar, but for some reason when I try to run the jar, it throws class not found. `java -cp bazel-bin/src/main/scala/com/azure/com.azure:test-core_2.12.jar src.main.scala.com.azure.AzureTest`   Is this not possible ? is there something that I'm missing ?

Comment: basically i need a jar to run inside azure synapse notebook. maven jars seems to work. but bazel `azuretest_deploy.jar` is not. though bazel `azuretest.jar` works but needs to add other individual dependency jars. now this maven `com.azure:test-core_2.12.jar` is also not working

Comment: did you look at contents of the jar with -xf flag?

Comment: the package name was the culprit, renaming it to azuretest.jar worked. But now the problem is its not picking up the dependency from the build file. Im using maven_install to pull dependencies, and not like mentioned in the article. probably that's why, I'm guessing. guess have implement it myself for this set up.

Comment: though....for some reasonn i can see the dependency in pom.xml but getting missing dependency on running the jar. any idea why that would happen @Natan ?

Comment: maybe you should try this: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external#publishing-to-external-repositories

Comment: Tried that but its expecting java source code. Im working on scala.